# (Python) OpenGL problems with ARB / EXT

Tags: python, opengl

I would like to write platform independent code, but I ran into problems. 
On some machines (windows/python OpenGL) `GL_VERTEX_SHADER` is defined, on others, `GL_VERTEX_SHADER_EXT` and yet others `GL_VERTEX_SHADER_ARB` is defined.
The same combination is also found using the functions `glCreateShaderObject`(EXT/ARB) and `glProgramParameteri`, and I must make sure to use the correct enum for those.
Is there a way (through profiles maybe?) to ensure that the machine you are on supports one combination of these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use these extensions unless you are targeting a version of OpenGL lower than 2.0. Honestly, why would you even bother supporting such old machines these days? There are too many inconvenient things you would have to do to maintain compatibility with implementations older than 2.0, including rescaling non-power-of-two textures.

> Is there a way (through profiles maybe?) to ensure that the machine you are on supports one combination of these?

Yes, if you establish OpenGL 2.0 as a baseline requirement for your software, then you can use the standard GLSL functions like: `glUseProgram (...)`. There is not a direct correspondence between the names used by the ARB extension and core GLSL, the ARB version of the function I just mentioned is `glUseProgramObjectARB (...)` for instance.

---

As for `glProgramParameteri` and its EXT/ARB variety, this is probably not what you think it is. It has nothing to do with `GL_VERTEX_SHADER`. Before being introduced into core (OpenGL 4.1), this function was provided through the extensions: `ARB_geometry_shader4` and `EXT_geometry_shader4`. It was first formally defined with the name `glProgramParameteri` by the extension: `ARB_get_program_binary` and may be present in a non-OpenGL 4.1 implementation if it provides this extension.

In short, if you have a compliant 4.1 implementation you are guaranteed to have a procedure address for `glProgramParameteri`. Otherwise the appropriate function to use depends on which of these appears in your extensions string:

```
 1. ARB_get_program_binary --> glProgramParameteri    (...)
 2. ARB_geometry_shader4   --> glProgramParameteriARB (...)
 3. EXT_geometry_shader4   --> glProgramParameteriEXT (...)
```

If none of these conditions are met, then you have no `glProgramParameteri` in any of its flavors.

Comment: Will try out this and accept answer if it works. (I must admit I don't  explicitly want to support old machines, its just that I learned OpenGL a long time ago ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Check out [GLee](http://elf-stone.com/glee.php):

> GLee (GL Easy Extension library) is a free cross-platform extension
>   loading library for OpenGL. It provides seamless support for OpenGL
>   functions up to version 3.0 and 399 extensions.
>
> **Compatibility**: GLee is compatible with Windows, Linux, OS-X and FreeBSD
>   platforms. It is also likely to be compatible with other unix-like
>   systems which use X windows.

Comment: I'm not lacking features. I get those using wglGetProcAddress. But, on some machines `wglGetProcAddress( glProgramParameteri )` works, but on others `wglGetProcAddress( glProgramParameteriEXT )` works.